# Which data type is arangodb storing auto-generated keys?

Tags: database, arangodb, aql

can anybody tell me which data type is arangodb storing his auto-generated _key's?

Is it number or string?

If i store a "foreign key" in a document from a dataset of antoher document, is it better for querys to store it as string or number?

Greetings mok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_key` attribute in every collection is always supposed to be a string, and only string values will be stored in it. 
So if your input data for `_key` is a number, it will be safest to convert it into a string first.